Proof Markov's Inequality
I have a question regarding the proof of Markov's Inequality, attached as a picture to the post, which is quite basic:
It is comphrensible that $\int_{a}^{\infty} xf(x) \, dx \geq \int_{a}^{\infty} af(x) \, dx$ holds. But how would I show that mathematically?


Since $x\in [a, \infty), $ this means $x\geq a. $ This implies $\int_a^\infty x ~f(x) ~\mathrm dx\geq \int_a^\infty a ~f(x) ~\mathrm dx. $

Oh of course, I thought to complicated. Thanks.
